# how to make a string which showed like an array return to array when add to an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, arrays, string

i got a string which was actually an array as I got it from database.
0
when i add it to an object, it becomes a string with quotation mark "" , but i want it to be array, what should I do?

e.g.

```
temp = [{"abc"=123},{"bcd"="234},...]  //this is actually a string
helloObj = {items:temp};
consol.log(helloObj); //will become items: "[{"abc"=123},{"bcd"="234},...]"
//I want it become items: [{"abc"=123},{"bcd"="234},...]

//I have tried below, not work:
temp = [temp];
helloObj = {items:temp};
consol.log(helloObj); //will become items: ["[{"abc"=123},{"bcd"="234},...]"
```

]

Comment: Thansk both! But I found I orinally should not make this happen.

Comment: I should originally in visual studio basic decode the json first before it become a json object, which is as below: jObjName["items"]=JsonObJsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(record.items);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is a JSON string. You need to parse it from the JSON notation which will convert it to an object (array in this case).

```
var aray = JSON.parse('[{"abc"=123},{"bcd"="234},...]');
console.log(aray);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you're getting JSON back from your database. Simply run `JSON.parse(str)` where `str` is your string and it will convert it back to an array.